# How to get the date this week from the day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for a way to return a short date value for a weekday in SQL Server.

for e.g. if the day is "Wednesday", then I want to return the date of the current week for a Wednesday. Assuming Monday is the first day of the week.

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks.

Comment: calculate difference between desired day of week and current day of week (for example 1/monday is desired, 2/tuesday today, so you have `1-2 == -1`), add this value to current date (ie `getdate() + -1`)

Comment: How would you call this? Is there a table column or kind of parameter with the content "Wednesday"? What if your solution would be installed in another culture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there's a better solution, but this gives you your desired result:

```
Declare @DayOfWeek Varchar (10) = 'Wednesday'

;With Date (Date) As
(
    Select  Convert(Date, DateAdd(Week, DateDiff(Week, 0, GetDate()), 0) - 1) Union All
    Select  DateAdd(Day, 1, Date)
    From    Date
    Where   Date < DateAdd(Day, 6, DateAdd(Week, DateDiff(Week, 0, GetDate()), 0) - 1)
)
Select  Date
From    Date
Where   DateName(WeekDay, Date) = @DayOfWeek
```

Result:

```
Date
2016-04-27
```